# The result is not a number

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Please help. What's wrong with this code? The task is follows:

> "Write a JavaScript code to divide an given array of positive integers into two parts. First element goes to first part, second element goes to second part, and third element goes to first part and so on. Now compute the sum of two parts and store into an array of size two."

This is my code:

```
function divArr(arr85) {
    let result = [0, 0]
    arr85.map(function(v, ind) {
        if (ind % 2 != 0) {
            result[0] += v[ind];
        } else if (ind % 2 == 0) {
            result[1] += v[ind];
        }
    })
    return result;
}
```

The reply is `[NAN,NAN]`.

I can't find the error.

Comment: what is contained in `arr85`?

Comment: The first parameter in `map` is an element (not an array).

Comment: console.log(divArr([1,2,3,4]))

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map. Your syntax for using `map` is incorrect. The first parameter must be a placeholder variable for a single element of the source array.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that the first argument/parameter in `Array.prototype.map()` refers to the item in the array, not the array itself. So, you only need to do `result[0] += v` instead of `result[0] = v[ind]`, for example.

See proof-of-concept code below:

```js
function divArr(arr85) {
    let result = [0, 0]
    arr85.map(function(v, ind) {
        if (ind % 2 != 0) {
            result[0] += v;
        } else if (ind % 2 == 0) {
            result[1] += v;
        }
    })
    return result;
}

console.log(divArr([1,2,3,4,5,6]));
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works now.